# creating ExtAudioFileRef from loaded memory buffer

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-audio

Is there a `function` in the apple libraries which can create an `ExtAudioFileRef` object from a given `memory buffer (say a void*)`. I have all my files concatenated into one memory buffer so I must only load a single file from drive then in memory split them up to use. I cannot keep the files seperate as this is a specification from my boss.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `AudioFileOpenWithCallbacks` and then `ExtAudioFileWrapAudioFileID` to do this.